# Getting Error ( Field xyzRepository (that extends JPA Repository) in abcService class required a bean of xyzRepository that could not be found

Tags: java

sipRepository.java

```
    import sip.sipDemo.model.mysql.SipEntity;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    @Component
    @Repository
    public interface SipRepository extends JpaRepository<SipEntity,Integer>{
    
    }
```

SipEntity.java

```
    package sip.sipDemo.model.mysql;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "sip_table")
    public class SipEntity {
    
          public SipEntity() {}
         @Id
         @Column(name = "id")
         @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
         private int id;
    
         @Column(name = "userid")
         private int UserId;
    
         @Column(name = "folioNo")
         private String FolioNo;
    
         @Column(name = "amount")
         private double Amount;
    
         @Column(name = "isin")
         private String IsIn;
    
         @Column(name = "schemename")
         private String SchemeName;
    
         @Column(name = "nextSipDate")
         private Date NextSipDate;
    
         @Column(name = "status")
         private String status;
    }
```

SipController.java

```
    package sip.sipDemo.Controller;
    import sip.sipDemo.Service.SipService;
    import sip.sipDemo.model.mysql.SipEntity;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    @Controller
    public class SipController {
    
         @Autowired
         private SipService sipservice;
    
    
        @ResponseBody
        @GetMapping(value="/")
        public String home()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    
        @ResponseBody
        @GetMapping(value = "/getAllEntities")
        public List<SipEntity> getAllEntities()
        {
             List<SipEntity> newList = sipservice.getAllEntities();
    
             return newList;
        }
    }
```

SipService.java

```
    package sip.sipDemo.Service;
    
    import sip.sipDemo.model.mysql.SipEntity;
    import sip.sipDemo.repository.mysql.SipRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    @Service
    public class SipService {
    
        @Autowired
        private SipRepository sipRepository;
    
        public List<SipEntity> getAllEntities()
        {
            List<SipEntity> sipList = sipRepository.findAll();
    
            return sipList;
        }
    }
```

sipDemoApplication.java (main file)

```
    package sip.sipDemo;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
    
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"sip.sipDemo"})
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SipDemoApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SipDemoApplication.class, args);
            
        }
    
    }
```

The Error Message looks like

```
: APPLICATION FAILED TO START

    ***************************
    
    Description:
    
    Field sipRepository in sip.sipDemo.Service.SipService required a bean of type 'sip.sipDemo.repository.mysql.SipRepository' that could not be found.
    
    The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    
    
    Action:
    
    Consider defining a bean of type 'sip.sipDemo.repository.mysql.SipRepository' in your configuration.
    
    
    > Task :SipDemoApplication.main() FAILED
```

application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys?autoReconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=******** (actual password)
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix=_AUDIT_LOG
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

1. I have used mysql database.
2. The main class is in the outer most layer and the packages are well structured.

```
   │   │               └── sipDemo
    │   │                   ├── Controller
    │   │                   │   └── SipController.java
    │   │                   ├── model
    │   │                   │   └── mysql
    │   │                   │       └── SipEntity.java
    │   │                   ├── repository
    │   │                   │   └── mysql
    │   │                   │       └── SipRepository.java
    │   │                   ├── Service
    │   │                   │   └── SipService.java
    │   │                   └── SipDemoApplication.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── application.properties
    │       ├── static
    │       └── templates
```

3. If I remove @Autowire for the sipRepository object in sipService, the controller endpoints for sipRepository do not work but the rest is working fine.
4. Please provide the possible source of error.